# WPF TwoWay Binding Custom with Data Provider

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to use twoway binding to a custom datasource (other than a db or xml where twoway binding is supported out of the box) in WPF to update the UI automatically when the source is updated and update the source when the object is changed in the UI.

What I currently have is a class, CacheObject, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and a custom (derived) ObservableCollection, CacheWrapper, which subscribes to changes in the cache and updates the appropriate CacheObject which in turn automatically updates the UI.

Is there a smart way that I can build into my CacheWrapper a way to update the cache - make a call using the cache API - when a CacheObject is updated in the list. If I subscribe to the PropertyChanged events I will receive events both when the objects are updated from code (changes from cache) and from the UI. Basically I want to do one thing if the update comes from the source and another if it comes from the target.

Some code examples.

**CacheObject**

```
public class CacheObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _key;
    private object _value;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public CacheObjectViewModel(object key, object value)
    {
        _key = key;
        _value = value;
    }

    public CacheObjectViewModel(KeyValuePair<object, object> keyValuePair)
        : this(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value)
    {
    }

    public object Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set
        {
            _key = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Key");
        }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

**CacheWrapper**

```
public class CacheWrapper : ObservableCollection<CacheObject>, ICacheObserver
{
    private ICache _cache;
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public CacheWrapepr(string name, ICache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        Name = name;

        cache.AddListener(this);
    }

    public void CacheEntryInserted(CacheEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        CacheObject cacheObject = eventArgs.NewElement as CacheObject;

        if(cacheObject != null)
        {
            this.Add(cacheObject);
        }
    }

    public void EntryUpdated(CacheEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        CacheObject cacheObjectNew = eventArgs.NewElement as CacheObject;

        if(cacheObjectNew != null)
        {
            CacheObject cacheObjectExisting = this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == cacheObjectNew.Key);

            if(cacheObjectExisting != null)
            {
                cacheObjectExisting.Value = cacheObjectNew.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void EntryDeleted(CacheEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        CacheObject cacheObject= = eventArgs.OldElement as CacheObject;

        if(cacheObject != null)
        {
            CacheObject cacheObjectExisting = this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == cacheObject.Key);

            if(cacheObjectExisting != null)
            {
                this.Remove(cacheObjectExisting);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help and ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like a simple converter would due the trick. http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: It doesn't even sound worthy of an `IValueConverter`... sounds more like the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface should take care of that for you. Surely you know when you are updating the object from code... all other changes must therefore come from the UI.

Comment: Sheridan, how do you susggest handling this in the INotifyPropertyChanged? PropertyChanged has to be fired in both cases to update the UI, but I don't know in the object implementation itself where the call came from (whether it was from another class in code or the UI).

Comment: Onosa, I could probably make it work using a value converter, I could also subscribe to the event triggered by my chosen UI control when the data changes (though I like the value converter better), but I was trying to find a more contained solution that with less dependency on WPF if possible. I appreciate the suggestion.